# Can libraries (eg. DLLs and SOs) be stateful?

Tags: dll, static, shared-libraries, stateful

I am wondering if libraries can be stateful.  In other words, can libraries store variables within themselves with persistent values?

I think the answer is "no" but I'm just trying to confirm.

Most libraries I have used are written in C and are not object-oriented.  They only consist of static functions which do work on a pointer you pass to them, but the actual block of memory pointed to by the pointer is physically located within the program's addressable space; not the library's.

Comment: Yes, they can. There's nothing to stop code in a DLL from allocating memory.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the case for C++ as well. Under the hood, I believe there are some functions that operate on structs.

Comment: If they did allocate their own memory, wouldn't that be a bad thing?  For example, App A and App B both use the same shared library.  App A uses the library and a persistent variable within the library is assigned the value 'a'.  App B does the same, and the same variable changes to 'b'.  App A is unaware of the change and still thinks the value is 'a'.

Comment: App A and App B would each have their own instance of the library (unless you do really funky stuff with shared memory)

Comment: You should write that as an answer so I can accept it :)